# Tengo un grafico con las letras en blanco y para imprimirlo estas letras tienen que estar en negro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eventos, print, color, text-color

tengo un grafico con palabras de color blanco y el fondo del grafico es gris, pero a la hora de imprimir en la preview el fondo es blanco (como lo quiero) i las letras blancas también. Por lo tanto necesito cambiar estas palabras para que a la hora de imprimir me salgan en color negro.

Gracias.

Comment: Sin ver el código, es difícil ayudarte. Pulsa en [edit] para mostrar un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una hoja de estilos CSS específica para medios de impresión. De esta manera, puedes cambiar el color del texto solo para la vista de impresión y no afectar la visualización en pantalla.

Agrega la siguiente etiqueta  en la sección  de tu archivo HTML:

```
<style>
    /* Estilos para la pantalla */
    .texto {
        color: white;
    }
    
    /* Estilos para la impresión */
    @media print {
        .texto {
            color: black;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Luego, aplica la clase texto a los elementos del gráfico cuyo color de texto deseas cambiar:

```
<div class="texto">Texto del gráfico</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer].

Comment: Cómo sabes que está relacionado con HTML o CSS? Cómo sabes si es XAML? Cómo sabes que no es React, Angular o VueJs, o cualquier otro front end framework de javascript? Si detalles como este no están claros, es mejor hacer preguntas en la sección de comentarios de la pregunta original.

Comment: Por favor, si no sabes del tema, es mejor evitar responder.

Comment: Y por cierto, mira este [artículo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Buenas tardes Sergio, estas usando ChatGPT?

Comment: no, no he usado ChatGPT. Me ha parecido una pregunta sencilla y la he respondido de la mejor manera que sabía.